Book/Course for undergraduates to learn stochastic processes
Currently, I'm reading about Denoising diffusion probabilistic models. The first time I heard about the idea of DDPM, I was thinking that "It's not possible! At least when implement using calculator, because of the limitation of the way we store floating number in form of bits. So
information surely all lost when so much noise added, then how can we reverse it?".
Looking DDPM at this perspective doesn't benefit to understand. I notice that there's something called "SDEs and reverse SDEs", which led me to stochastic process, and I think it's the answer for all of my question.
Unfortunately, Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Probability were taught at a very elementary level in my university, so even though I try to search and read a lot but it seems that all resources require a much higher level of understanding. For example, I encounter many unfamiliar terms such as $\sigma$-algebra, measurement theory, etc...
Is there any material suitable for my level of understanding?

Not a book or a course as you want, but take a look at this answer on the sister site dsp.SE which also has many other questions and answers on stochastic processes  at a level suitable for beginners; in contrast to stats,SE or math.SE where the questions and answers tend to be at a higher level and talk of $\sigma$-algebras, measure theory (not measurement theory as you call it).

Very helpful, thanks!
